# Latencia en trasferencia de datos

Tags: c#, backend, patrones-de-diseño

Trabajo en el backend de un sistema POS, el mismo es hecho con asp.net web api(C#). Desde hace un par de dias intento reestructurar el código pues al inicio estaba bastante desorganizado. Para esto he planteado un modelo de 3 capas Modelo-Logica-Presentacion. A continuación presentó  un ejemplo

**Modelo**

```
namespace api.Models.All
{
  [Table(Name ="ventas")]
  public partial class Venta
  {
      [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, IsDbGenerated = true)]
      public int id { get; set; }
      [Column]
      public int idEmpresa { get; set; }
      [Column]
      public int? idCliente { get; set; }
      [Column]
      public int idResponsable { get; set; }
      [Column]
      public string referencia { get; set; }
      [Column]
      public int recibo { get; set; }
      ...
  }
}
```

**Logica**

```
namespace api.Models.All
{
  public partial class Venta
  {
    private readonly DbAll dbAll = new DbAll();

    public List<Venta> getByTrade(int idTrade, int idEmployee, int idPosition) {
        try
        {
            List<Venta> ventas = new List<Venta>();
            if (idPosition == 1)
            {
                ventas = dbAll.ventas.Where(i => i.idEmpresa == idTrade && i.estado == true).OrderByDescending(i => i.id).Take(200).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                ventas = dbAll.ventas.Where(i => i.idEmpresa == idTrade && i.estado == true && i.idResponsable == idEmployee).OrderByDescending(i => i.id).Take(200).ToList();
            }
            foreach (var item in ventas)
            {
                item.fechaRegistro = item.fechaRegistro.AddHours(-5);
                item.empleado = dbAll.empleados.Single(i => i.id == item.idResponsable);
                item.productos = dbAll.detalleVentas.Where(i => i.idVenta == item.id && i.estado == true).ToList();
            }
            return ventas;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return new List<Venta>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Presentacion**

```
public class VentaController : ApiController
    {
        Respuesta respuesta = new Respuesta();
        
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Venta")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetByTrade(int idEmpresa, int idEmpleado, int idCargo)
        {
            return Ok(respuesta.ok(new Venta().getByTrade(idEmpresa, idEmpleado, idCargo)));
        }
}
```

**Base datos**

```
 public class DbAll : DataContext
    {
        ...
        public Table<Venta> ventas;
        ...

        public DbAll() : base(@"...") { }

    }
```

Como menciono en el titulo de esta pregunta, si bien el funcionamiento del código no se ha alterado, los tiempos de respuesta se han incrementado, inclusive una consulta que retorna 1250 registros de venta tarda mas de un minuto y medio. Qué me recomendarían para agilizar el tiempo de respuesta, algún patron de diseño en particular.

Algo en particular que podría mencionar es que las clases para la lógica y el modelo están en carpetas diferentes pero se ha renombrado el espacio de nombres para que tenga efecto el `partial class`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Pues lo primero que necesitas verificar son las consultas, realiza pruebas con queries e la Base de  datos, si es muy lento digamos mas de 5 seg, debes reedisenar la base de datos. o algunas tablas

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, en general suelen tardar entre 1 y 3 seg para las consultas simple. Cuando se trabaja con joins y demás el tiempo suele subir a unos 6 u 8 segundos como máximo

Comment: y este tipo de operaciones cuanto tarda? dbAll.ventas.Where(i => i.idEmpresa == idTrade && i.estado == true).OrderByDescending(i => i.id).Take(200).ToList();

Comment: Ahí es donde el mayor problema, pues en esa consulta el servidor toma unos 4 segundos (para los 200 registros) si dejo que devuelva todos los registros se demora muchísimo más e incluso genera timeouts en el lado del cliente (60s por defecto)

Comment: Mueve esa consulta a BD parametrisada es decir crea un store procedure,  y verfica como estan compuestos los indices en tu tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá no es la mejor solución pero opte por implementar el método Dispose en mis clases que contengan la lógica del negocio.

```
public partial class Venta: IDisposable
{
  private readonly DbAll dbAll = new DbAll();
  public List<Venta> getByTrade(int idTrade, int idEmployee, int idPosition) {
    try
    {
        List<Venta> ventas = new List<Venta>();
        if (idPosition == 1)
        {
            ventas = dbAll.ventas.Where(i => i.idEmpresa == idTrade && i.estado == true).OrderByDescending(i => i.id).Take(200).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            ventas = dbAll.ventas.Where(i => i.idEmpresa == idTrade && i.estado == true && i.idResponsable == idEmployee).OrderByDescending(i => i.id).Take(200).ToList();
        }
        foreach (var item in ventas)
        {
            item.fechaRegistro = item.fechaRegistro.AddHours(-5);
            item.empleado = dbAll.empleados.Single(i => i.id == item.idResponsable);
            item.productos = dbAll.detalleVentas.Where(i => i.idVenta == item.id && i.estado == true).ToList();
        }
        return ventas;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return new List<Venta>();
    }
   }

public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            dbAll.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto se supero el error en gran medida la latencia y por ende los timeouts generados en el cliente, otra medida que implementare será pasar ciertas consultas a la base de datos con base en las recomendaciones que me dieron.

Muchas gracias